# html code as string double quotations inside single quotations

Tags: flutter

Using html code as a string I get error because there is double quotation "" inside a single quotation ''
**what to edit to fix this error this is my code**

```
WebView(
                  initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString( '<!DOCTYPE html>
                      <html>
                      <body>

                      <video width="400" controls>
                      <source src="http://server105.akoams.com/dl/1575672987/The.Blue.Elephant.2.akoam.net.mkv" type="video/mp4">
                      </video>

                      </body>
                      </html>',
                      mimeType: 'text/html')
                      .toString(),
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

                )
```

Comment: Try escaping the double quotes.

Comment: how ? my html wont work properly like this

Comment: could you provide me an example as an answer?

Comment: Just turn all `"` into `\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to escape a long string directly use triple quote ''' before and end of the long string 
you do not have to escape each one

code snippet

```
return WebView(
            initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString( '''<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <body>

                <video width="400" controls>
                <source src="http://server105.akoams.com/dl/1575672987/The.Blue.Elephant.2.akoam.net.mkv" type="video/mp4">
                </video>

                </body>
                </html>''',
                mimeType: 'text/html')
                .toString(),
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

          );
```